# Merge Replication - Detect nonlogged agent shutdown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, merge-replication

I have never worked with SQL Server replication and am now in an environment with SQL Server 2012 merge replication. On 3/29 and 3/30 there are 13 of 19 replication jobs which are failing with detect nonlogged agent shutdown on the subscribers.

The publisher and distributor are on the same server. There are 2 publications which are failing. Some of the errors are

> The process could not connect to Subscriber

and some errors are

> The merge process failed because it detected a mismatch between the replication metadata of the two replicas

I am able to successfully ping the publisher from the subscribers.

All revalidations are failing. Do I need to recreate the subscribers? SQL Server Express is running on the subscribers.

Thanks..

Comment: From time to time replication can fail for many reasons. In transactional replication it is possible to fix a hung transaction, perhaps someone updated a record at the subscriber by accident, or whatever. Usually, enough info can be gathered by the Replication Monitor to determine if the replication can be fixed. In some situations you may find the only resolution is to create a new snapshot :(

Comment: As far as the agent shutdown, what is reported when you View Synchronization Status?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: The following error is listed:  The process could not connect to Subscriber 'UP002'.
Client unable to establish connection because an error was encountered during handshakes before login. Common causes include client attempting to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server, server too busy to accept new connections or a resource limitation (memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 26)

Client unable to establish connection (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 26)